# Java Script Function Methods

Tags: javascript, function

What is the different between following two methods of defining js function. I have seen this is some code some one given, but could not able to call the function inside of it.

**1)**

```
function sum () {
    var i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
return sum;
};
```

**2)**

```
var sum = function () {
    var i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the var one is defined after the var is created, whereas the static one is defined without waiting for a var to get referenced.
You can call the "var one" only after you declare it since it is "known" at run-time.

example:

```
a(); // error - doesn't know a
var a = function(){alert('a')}

b(); // ok
function b(){ alert('b')}
```

Comment: So, can i access variables define in the var function?

Comment: vars inside the function have their own scope.

Comment: They're both defined at runtime. Neither could possibly exist while the program is being parsed.

Comment: could you give me some sample tutorial links to study?

Comment: @Nisala: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions, http://quirksmode.org/js/function.html, http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html

Comment: @cookiemonster - I mean't that one is "known" in "real time" and therefore you can't invoke it before the var is declared.

Comment: @Amir: FWIW, the variable is also declared before the code is executed, but the assignment hasn't taken place yet. If the variable wasn't declared, you'd get a reference error. And this isn't specific to function expressions of course, every variable declarations work like this.

Comment: @FelixKling - that's what I was trying to explain, but maybe I wasn't clear enough..

Comment: Could you please explain me that how can i access "current" variable in this function. I cant paste all the code here (dont have space)
`var PageTransitions = (function() {
 var $main = 
  $( '#pt-main' ),
  animcursor = 1,
  pagesCount = $pages.length,
  current = 0;
});`

Answer (score 0):

First can be used before declaring but second can be used only after its declaration..